# Stop my task and all my waiting task

Tags: c#, winforms

i have an application who take all the added files from my `Listbox` and play this files:

```
IEnumerable<string> source

public void play()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(source,
                         new ParallelOptions
                         {
                             MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 //limit number of parallel threads 
                         },
                         file =>
                         {
                              //each file process via another class
                         });
    }).ContinueWith(
            t =>
            {
                OnFinishPlayEvent();
            }
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
        );
    }
```

my processing file can be stop via my class property but if i want to stop all the files
that waiting how can i do it ?

Comment: Why use a parallel loop if want sequential processing?

Comment: There's a `TaskFactory` constructor that takes a Cancellation Token parameter - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992588.aspx

Comment: @Bridge That won't actually be enough - you need to explicitly handle it within the `Parallel.For` loop (1CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`).  Passing it to the `TaskFactory` will only prevent the original task from being scheduled, but that will most likely happen prior to any cancel request.

Comment: If you're going to set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to 1, you should consider just using a normal `foreach`...

Comment: I want it have the option to configure it in the future

Answer (score 1):

You need to design your routines to accept a [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx), and then trigger a [`CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321955.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

This will allow you to provide a mechanism to cooperatively cancel your work.

For details, see [Cancellation in Managed Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) and [Task Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: @user2214609 You should spend some time and effort attempting a solution on your own first.  That you're new makes it all the more important for you to experiment on your own so that you can more thoroughly learn the material, rather than just having Reed give you the code.  He has provided you with links to resources that will show examples of similar but different situations that you can use to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop a parallel loop, use an instance of the `ParallelLoopState` class. To cancel a task, you want to use a `CancellationToken`. Since you are embedding your parallel loop inside a task, you can simply pass a cancellation token into the task. Bear in mind, this will throw an OperationCanceledException you will have to catch, if you choose to wait on your task(s).

For example, and for the sake of argument, we'll assume that something else will call a delegate inside your class that will set the cancellation token.

```
CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

//Let's assume this is set as the delegate to some other event
//that requests cancellation of your task
void Cancel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _tokenSource.Cancel();
}

void DoSomething()
{
  var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
    // Your code here...
  }, _tokenSource.Token);

  try {
    task.Wait();
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException) {
    //Carry on, logging that the task was canceled, if you like
  }
  catch (AggregateException ax) {
    //Your task will throw an AggregateException if an unhandled exception is thrown
    //from the worker. You will want to use this block to do whatever exception handling
    //you do.
  }
}
```

Bear in mind, there are better ways to do this (and I'm typing from memory here, so there could be some syntax errors and the like), but this should get you started.

Comment: Still continue after the cancellation