# Cancel my task parallel loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application who take all the added files from Listbox and play this file.

this is the class that take `IEnumerable<string> source` and play the files via another class:

```
public CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource { get; set; }
private IEnumerable<string> _source;

    public void play(PacketDevice selectedOutputDevice, double speed, int parallelThreads)
    {
        var token = _tokenSource.Token;
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(_source,
                    new ParallelOptions
                    {
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;
                    },
                    file =>
                    {
                        processFile(file, selectedOutputDevice, speed, parallelThreads);
                        //token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    });
            }
            catch (AggregateException)
            {

            }

        }, _tokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(
                t =>
                {
                    OnFinishPlayEvent();
                }
            , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
            );
    }
```

And from the main form under Stop button click event i am change `_tokenSource.Cancel();` but my problem is that my loop continue to work and not stopping.

Comment: Can you demonstrate this in a short but complete program? It really looks like it *should* work. It won't cancel the current processing tasks, but it should avoid starting any new ones... That's assuming you're actually getting to the cancellation code. The call to `Task.WaitAll` is ominous... are you sure it's not just blocking there?

Comment: Actually, you're not passing any tasks to `Task.WaitAll`, so I don't think it's doing *anything* - you should get rid of the whole try/catch block to avoid confusion.

Comment: Related question of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900703/stop-my-task-and-all-my-waiting-task it seems to be very much overlapped with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the cancel request manually within `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
var token = _tokenSource.Token;

Parallel.ForEach(_source,
    new ParallelOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1//limit number of parallel threads 
    },
    file =>
    {
        //here i am process my file via another class

        // Cancel if required
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    });
```

That being said, if you're going to set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1`, there is no reason to use `Parallel.ForEach`, as it will effectively run sequentially.

Comment: MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 is only for this time cause i am using several usually

Comment: It working but have OperationCanceledException exception and if i put the code inside Try Catch it doesn't stop

Comment: @user2214609 Wrap *only* Parallel.ForEach in an exception handler, not the entire block.  It'll catch the cancellation exception then.

Comment: @user2214609 Catch AggregateException as well.

Comment: Not AggregateException and not Exception, in both way i got the Exception

Comment: @user2214609 You can always just return if a cancel was requested instead of throwing.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.iscancellationrequested.aspx

Comment: See my update: still continue to the next file without stopping

Comment: @user2214609 Put the return BEFORE your work - so you exit out before you do anything.

Comment: Also i put it inside Task.Factory... and it still not working